# get a simple array of all of the term names that exist in all taxonomies

Tags: php, functions, array, terms

I may be going about this all wrong but I'm trying to use get terms to get all of the terms that exist in every taxonomy.

I think this might be a php question.

get_terms allows you to specify which taxonomies it gets terms from in array like this...

```
get_terms( array(post_tag, category, nav_menu, link_category, post_format), $args )
```

That works, but I'm writing a plugin and if people have custom taxonomies manually entering the array will not work.
So I figured the solution would be to use get taxonomies to generate that array. The problem is, it comes back as an associatave array and I need a simple array. So I did this...

```
$myarray = 'array('. implode(', ',get_taxonomies('','names')) .')';
```

which, if I echo $myarray, returns:
array(category, post_tag, nav_menu, link_category, post_format)

perfect; That's exactly what I have manually entered. now I should be able to stick $myarray in get_get terms where I have it manually entered and it should get everything.
Nope. It doesn't like it.

Here's the entire snippet of code, along with a pic of what get's echoed out. You can see that $myarray is exactly the same as what's in the working get_terms but it's breaking the second get_terms.

```
$myarray = 'array('. implode(', ',get_taxonomies('','names')) .')';

echo $myarray . '<br/>';
echo 'array(category, post_tag, nav_menu, link_category, post_format) <br/><br/>';

print_r(get_terms( array(post_tag, category, nav_menu, link_category, post_format), $args )); echo '<br /><br />';
print_r(get_terms( $myarray , $args )); echo '<br /><br />';
```

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aE8C.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I don't know what I was doing wrong because I tried this before and couldn't get it to work but I ended up using `array_values()` after a couple of people recommended it in another thread.

I finally ended up writing it like this:

```
get_terms( array_values((get_taxonomies('','names'))) , $args );
```